# Why won't a Search REST API request not work on all Site Collections?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, search-api

My organization has a SharePoint Online tenancy.

I created a Test Site collection as a Subsite of the main Site Collection.  I'm able to submit the following REST call through a chrome browser, and I receive an XML response.

The Test site collection has a URL of:

`tenancy.sharepoint.com/sites/Test`

REST API Call: `tenancy.sharepoint.com/Test/_api/search/query?querytext=%27focusing%27`

Response: I get a properly formatted XML response.

I then created a Site Collection, that was not a subsite of the main Site Collection.  This was intended to be for our production environment.

statistics URL:
`tenancy.sharepoint.com/sites/statistics`

REST API Call: `tenancy.sharepoint.com/statistics/_api/search/query?querytext=%27focusing%27`

Response: NOTHING.  The browser's screen goes white, but never loads anything.  Completely white.  I leave it for 30 minutes, it stays white.  It doesn't give any indication of an error, timeout, or it trying to still do something.  It just doesn't do anything.

Questions:
Is the Search REST API only available to the main site collection and its subsites??

Is there something that needs to be enabled on a Site Collection to allow the REST API to even work?  We didn't appear to need to make any such configuration setting for the main Site Collection, it just worked when we first started exploring its capabilities.

Please help.  We're new to SharePoint and are constantly running into roadblocks.

Comment: How are you running these REST calls? Browser? JavaScript? C#?

Comment: Through a browser.  I'm using a Chrome browser.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your URL, it is created under the sites managed path,`tenancy.sharepoint.com/sites/statistics`

So your REST call would be `tenancy.sharepoint.com/sites/statistics/_api/search/query?querytext=%27focusing%27`. `tenancy.sharepoint.com/statistics` isn't valid.

Comment: Using sites/statistics does return a response, however all the documents returned are from the sites/Test site collection, none from the site/statistics site collection are returned.

Comment: It's possible the search services have not crawled your content yet.

Comment: The content has been up on the site for over a week.

I have also verified that under the Site Collection's - Site Settings > Search and Offline Availability that the "Allow this site to appear in search results?" is set to yes.